# Repository pattern is not correctly returning LiveData

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am using MVVM, LiveData and trying and implement Repository pattern.

But, calling a method in my repository class - `RegisterRepo` which returns `LiveData` is not working. I have no idea why. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Boilerplate code is removed for breivity.

`Activity`' s `onCreateMethod`

```
mViewModel.status.observe(this, Observer {
            when (it) {
                true ->  {
                    Log.d("----------", " true ") //These message is never being printed. 
                }
                false -> {
                    Log.d("----------", "false ") //These message is never being printed. 

                }
            }
        })

button.setOnClickListener {
   mViewModel.a()
}
```

`ViewModel`

```
class AuthViewModel (val repo: RegisterRepo): ParentViewModel() {
   //...

    var status = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    fun a() {
        status = repo.a()
    }
}
```

`RegisterRepo`

```
class RegisterRepo () {

fun a(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
        var result = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
        result.value = true

        return result
    }

}
```

However, if I change my code in `ViewModel` to this, everything is working fine.

`ViewModel`

```
class AuthViewModel (val repo: RegisterRepo): ParentViewModel() {
   //...

    var status = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    fun a() {
        status.value = true //Change here causing everything work as expected. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first ViewModel code, when method `a` is called, you assign another `LiveData` to `status` variable, this live data is different from the one observed by the `Activity`, so that the value won't be notify to your `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

the 2nd way is correct to use and it will work fine the 1st is not working because you are creating new MutableLive data in your RegisterRepo, so basically at the time your create an observable to "status" is deferent where you assign a value into it is different. so the second one is the only way to do this